# How to include a persistent volume claim when using Memgraph on Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, memgraphdb

I run Memgraph on Kubernetes using the sample service+deployment found in the memgraph/bolt-proxy repo. Unfortunately, that config doesn’t include a persistent volume claim. I'd like to keep Memgraph’s log and snapshots persistent in Kubernetes. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure a Pod to Use a PersistentVolume for Storage
This page shows you how to configure a Pod to use a PersistentVolumeClaim for storage. Here is a summary of the process:

[View More Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/)

Answer (score 0):

There are some [Helm Charts](https://helm.sh/) for Memgraph that do include `PersistentVolumeClaim`.

Memgraph itself is a `StatefulSet` since it is not stateless. The StatefulSet is then provided with three volumes. Two of them are volume claims (`lib` and `log`), and the 3rd one is the `config`.